# Exception with Axiom and Spring WS Integration

Tags: spring, web-services

We are using Spring Web services version 2.1.3 with Axiom Api version 1.2.14, and Spring core version 3.1.0 to expose web services using `AxiomSoapMessageFactory` but the exception below is thrown. I have tried with different Axiom Api versions but I am still unable still unable to resolve the issue. I'm using WebSphere 7 and Java 6.

```
4/25/16 16:41:28:006 MST] 0000002c ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service CWSRV0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet spring-ws in application emmam1. Exception created : org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/axiom/soap/SOAPFactory.createOMElement(Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMDataSource;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMSourcedElement;
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:576)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:250)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1694)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1635)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:965)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3994)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/axiom/soap/SOAPFactory.createOMElement(Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMDataSource;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMSourcedElement;
        at org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapBody.setStreamingPayload(AxiomSoapBody.java:71)
        at org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessage.setStreamingPayload(AxiomSoapMessage.java:175)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.marshalToResponsePayload(AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.JaxbElementPayloadMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(JaxbElementPayloadMethodProcessor.java:60)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.handleMethodReturnValue(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:295)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.invokeInternal(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:248)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.invoke(AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:233)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:173)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:59)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:239)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        ... 28 more

[4/25/16 16:41:28:024 MST] 0000002c FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident CWRDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /opt/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/wsfpp1/logs/ffdc/wsfpp1lpdza653emmam1Server_543c543c_16.04.25_16.41.28.0108470346255677976768.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter 82
[4/25/16 16:41:28:024 MST] 0000002c FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident CWRDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /opt/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/wsfpp1/logs/ffdc/wsfpp1lpdza653emmam1Server_543c543c_16.04.25_16.41.28.0241260189154356098319.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest() 309
[4/25/16 16:41:28:027 MST] 0000002c webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError CWSRV0293E: [Servlet Error]-[spring-ws]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/axiom/soap/SOAPFactory.createOMElement(Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMDataSource;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMSourcedElement;
        at org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapBody.setStreamingPayload(AxiomSoapBody.java:71)
        at org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessage.setStreamingPayload(AxiomSoapMessage.java:175)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.marshalToResponsePayload(AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.JaxbElementPayloadMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(JaxbElementPayloadMethodProcessor.java:60)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.handleMethodReturnValue(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:295)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.invokeInternal(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:248)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.invoke(AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:233)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:173)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:59)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:239)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:576)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:250)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1694)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1635)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:965)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3994)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
```

Comment: When you fill out a question, if you highlight code (or exceptions) and click the {} then it will insert four spaces which will convert it into a code block. Also, no need to say 'Thanks' at the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the presence of ancient Apache Axiom code in the WebSphere runtime. The solution is to configure your application to switch the class loading policy to parent last.